# -o: command not found

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to download file using curl, but I get the following error message.

> -o: command not found

My command was

```
curl http://lab.test.com/test/test/down.php?c=redsoul&bbs_no=236513&file_num=7061013&filename=%EC%95%84%EC%9D%B4%EC%96%B8%EB%A7%A8%2003%ED%99%94%20%28ANIMAX%201280x720%20x264%20AAC%29.SMI&size=25485 -o 'saveas.smi'
```

Do I have error with my command?

Comment: question does not belong here

Comment: Retagged your question since your issue is with how bash escapes special characters, not with curl.

Comment: @N, no, but kind of a little. Bash is after all a programming language, too.

Comment: @N 1.1 // Sorry. I think it belongs to superuser.com.

Comment: Or maybe serverfault.com?  It is more of a server admin thing to muck around with scripts, right?

Answer (score 6):

Your command looks OK, but you also need to quote the URL, like so:

```
curl 'http://lab.test.com/test/test/down.php?c=redsoul&bbs_no=236513&file_num=7061013&filename=%EC%95%84%EC%9D%B4%EC%96%B8%EB%A7%A8%2003%ED%99%94%20%28ANIMAX%201280x720%20x264%20AAC%29.SMI&size=25485' -o 'saveas.smi'
```

Comment: Oh yes, with all those `&` characters it is wise to quote the URL.

Comment: What it did here was separating several commands: `curl http://lab.test.com/test/test/down.php?c=redsoul`, `bbs_no=236513`, etc. all of them are valid (variable assignments in bash)… except the last `-o` which follows a variable assignement and therefore is an other command